# firebird 2.5 wait for one trigger from another

Tags: triggers, firebird, wait, firebird2.5

In *table 1* I have *trigger 1* that inserts in *table 3* with *trigger 3* that uses results of *trigger 2* in *table 2*.
Is there is a way in Firebird 2.5 to lunch *trigger 1* in *table 1* only after *trigger 2* in *table 2*?
Maybe some "wait for trigger"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in Firebird 2.5 you can't specify the trigger to only run after some other trigger.

The execution order of triggers is determined by the order of statements that trigger them, ie if you use

```
INSERT INTO table2 ...
INSERT INTO table1 ...
```

then the (`ON INSERT`) triggers of the `table2` is executed before `table1` ones. If table has more than one trigger of given type then the order is determined by the `POSITION` clause of the trigger's declaration.

If you can't guarantee the order of `INSERT` statements then perhaps you can use database trigger as a workaround - create an `ON TRANSACTION COMMIT` trigger where you check for a flag you did set in the `trigger2`. If the flag is there then execute the stuff which requires the data generated in the `trigger2`. For setting up the flag you can use the [RDB$SET_CONTEXT](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-set_context.html) with the `USER_TRANSACTION` namespace. Something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger2 ACTIVE AFTER INSERT ON table2
AS
BEGIN
  RDB$SET_CONTEXT ('USER_TRANSACTION', 'doTrigger1', 1);
END

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 ACTIVE ON TRANSACTION COMMIT
AS
BEGIN
  IF(RDB$GET_CONTEXT ('USER_TRANSACTION', 'doTrigger1') = 1)THEN BEGIN
     -- proccess data
  END
END
```

See the Firebirds language reference for the complete [TRIGGER DDL syntax](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-ddl-trigger.html).